# bokeh: grid alignment for two plots in one row

Tags: bokeh

I have a bokeh plot with two subplots in a row representing different types of data view (lines and hbars). Both subplots has the same y-axis values, total height and it's expected that grid lines representing y-ticks also will be aligned in one line. However it's not the case (see at the picture):
[image]

I suspect that there are two ways to solve the issue: 1) find some options which will align them automatically; 2) manually control paramer value responsible for offset from x-asis to first y-tick.

However I don't know bokeh enough to go for any of such solutions. Please advise if there are some parameter to fix it or probably totally different way around. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your #2 solution will work fine. You can manually set the `y_range` to be what you want. Here's an example of the same plot data in plots with y_range defined or not:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import Row, Column

x = [0,   1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6]
y = [43, 45, 32, 50, 28, 30, 31]
z = [50, 52, 35, 28, 45, 47, 43]

p1 = figure(width=400, height=300)
p1.line(x=x, y=y, color='red')

p2 = figure(width=400, height=300)
p2.line(x=x, y=z, color='blue')

p3 = figure(width=400, height=300, y_range=(0, 60))
p3.line(x=x, y=y, color='red')

p4 = figure(width=400, height=300, y_range=(0, 60))
p4.line(x=x, y=z, color='blue')

row_1 = Row(p1, p2)
row_2 = Row(p3, p4)
col = Column(row_1, row_2)

show(col)
```

Another way to achieve a similar result without being quite so specific is to have the y_range of one refer to the other. So you could let p3 figure out what it needs the range to be, and then define p4 as:

```
p4 = figure(width=400, height=300, y_range=p3.y_range)
```

As a third alternative, you can explicity set the start/end of ranges as you need to, after the plot is defined:

```
p4.y_range.start = min(your_data_list)
p4.y_range.end = max(your_data_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, copying of y_range property works just perfect. I forgot about this for some reason ) Nice catch!